# how to enable APC caching in xampp v3.2.1

Tags: caching, xampp, apc

I am using `xampp v3.2.1` with `PHP 5.6.8`. now i want to use PHP APC caching techiniques but unable to use. can anyone please tell how shall i enable this caching on my xampp.

Answer (score 1):

In short: when you are using PHP 5.6.8:

- enable the Opcache
- forget about APC
- if you need a userland cache use APCu

Since PHP 5.5 the Bytecode-Cache "OpCache" is part of the core, making the APC extension itself useless. In other words: APC is only usefull for 5.4 and lower versions and those reached EOL.

Since PHP 5.5 there is the User Cache-Extension "APCu" as a replacement for APC. 
https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu